# Game mechanics - how do I keep running a PHP script in the background even when all the players go offline?

Tags: php, ajax, connection, client-server, background-process

I am trying to create a **multi-player, PHP+JS-powered card game (2-6 players)**.

When a player chooses a card from his/her hand, I pass on that information to the other players by updating and then retrieving the details using a database/file *(haven't decided which one, but that's not the issue here).*

If it is a player's turn to choose a card and they don't, the system selects one of the cards and drops it for them. Whether it's a manual choice or a system choice, the same mechanism of using a central database/file to update the others' interfaces is used. As long as there is an AJAX call being made to update the database, it is all well and good.

**But if any of the players lose connectivity or close the browser,** there won't be a fresh AJAX call anymore from their turn. Even this can be managed with polling being done from other players' scripts (do let me know if there is a better, more efficient way of doing this - but again, not my MAIN question here).

**If all players lose connectivity, there is no AJAX call from any of them, and the game "goes into a coma" there:** there is no client calling the PHP script that manages the game, and that means nothing more happens in the game. No new rounds, no automatic card selection.

**So is there a way to keep the PHP script alive (simulating player inputs till the logical end of the game) even after all the players have gone offline?**

To answer a likely question: If there is no solution or workaround to this, I can accept that if ALL players have dropped off, I can leave that game in a state of suspended animation. I might still do this anyway, but I'd like to know anyway if there's a way to keep the game's script running until the game is over (all cards exhausted)?

Comment: An idea would be to do the mechanics on the serverside (Node.js?)

Comment: @DieterKräutl why nodeJS, when PHP is already being used?

Comment: A better approach to this game overall would be using websockets rather than AJAX. You'll know when a client is gone because the websocket connection will close.

Comment: Have considered websockets, but I can't think of enough advantages over AJAX (at the present time) to warrant the additional complexities of managing a websocket here. I'll revisit this decision if this breaks the multi-player game experience completely, but not otherwise.

Comment: If you are open to using an alternative technology stack such as ASP.NET Core with SignalR, then almost all the complexity of managing websockets is abstracted away.  You can get up and running in a few minutes. PHP's websocket implementations are mostly not very usable, by contrast. (You could even integrate Azure SignalR with PHP if you wanted to, although it's not as seamless as using it with an ASP.NET application).

Comment: Thanks, @ADyson. But not moving away from PHP at the moment. This is more of a hobby project at the moment, and picking up a new language is out of my scope. The learning time will kill my momentum.

Comment: Fair enough. The Azure Signalr integration with PHP route might still be an option though since it's essentially software-as-a-service so you won't need to know any C# code for that I don't think. And there's quite a high free allowance so it needn't cost much, if anything.